# Why mysql function returned value -1 in c++?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, database

```
bool MySql_Register(const char* id, const char* pw) {
  MYSQL* connect_ptr;
  connect_ptr = mysql_init(NULL);
  if(!mysql_real_connect(connect_ptr, HOST, USER, PW, NAME, 3306, NULL, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s ",mysql_error(connect_ptr));
    exit(1);
  }

  char sql[256] = {0};
  sprintf(sql, "select * from user where id='%s'", id);
  mysql_query(connect_ptr, sql);
  int len = mysql_affected_rows(connect_ptr);

  if(len == 1)
    return PK_ID_OVERLAP;
  sprintf(sql, "insert into user (id, pw) values ('%s', '%s')", id, pw);
  mysql_query(connect_ptr, sql);
  len = mysql_affected_rows(connect_ptr);

  if(len == 1)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

`mysql_connect` and `mysql_query` running is very well.
 but `mysql_affected_rows` returned value -1.
I don't know where is the problem....

Comment: C is not the same as C++ .. please choose one of them.

Comment: There's a terrifying lack of proper SQL escaping in there and this thing is probably a giant [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). I don't often see that in C code.

Comment: I think -1 is correct for the select query, a SELECT command does not affect any rows, so there should be another function get the row count from connect_ptr, the insert should actually return a valid result but did you check if the row was actually inserted ?

Comment: BTW did you consider using really the c++ connector instead of the plain c, looks like there are more examples and a better support.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html):

> -1 indicates that the query returned an error or that, for a SELECT query, mysql_affected_rows() was called prior to calling
>   mysql_store_result()

Moreover, I suggest you to use prepared statements instead of `sprintf` to avoid SQL injections.